# URL redirect without changing url in address bar

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have created this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/some-page/(.*)/ $1/other-page/$2 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

but when I access url eg. wwww.example.com/en/some-page/test/
then it will redirect to wwww.example.com/en/other-page/test

I dont want to change URL just need to display content of "other-page"

Comment: Remove the R=301 flag, that tells the browser to redirect. Without it the user will continue to see `wwww.example.com/en/some-page/test` in the address bar but will get the contents of `other-page`. Note that browsers cache 301 redirects so you will need to make sure you have cleared it from the browser cache when you re-test.

Comment: I have remove R=301 and clear browser cache now its display 404 page not found

Comment: Is there actually a file at the address: `www.example.com/en/other-page/test`? This rule is expecting a file named `test`, with no extension, in the directory `en/other-page/`.